# Rhel 7–> 8 upgrade default Python version is changing automatically

Tags: linux, ansible, python, rhel7

I am trying to upgrade rhel7 to Rhel8 using leap upgrade tool using ansible.
But my rhel7 server is treating me wired.
Currently RHEL7.9 machine is pointing to python2 but when I reboot the machine then it automatically point my default python to python3 which is not at all installed.

**Before reboot**

> /usr/bin/python-> /etc/alternatives/python
> /etc/alternatives/python -> /usr/bin/**python2**

**After reboot**

> /usr/bin/python-> /etc/alternatives/python /etc/alternatives/python
> -> /usr/bin/**python3**

Answer (score 2):

Install python3 if you wish to use Python for scripting or applications.

Review Python applications installed as rpms. Ideally they follow Fedora python packaging guidelines, in which case they should have dependencies that ultimately pull in a python environment.

However, you likely use python interactively, in ad-hoc scripts, or with other package managers. In which case add `python3` to the list of packages installed by your automation.

System applications such as dnf continued to work because EL8 has a separate platform-python interpreter. Ignore this as an internal to the distro thing. The python to use are the newer version ones in appstream repo.

Comment: Thank you I found it there is one customized service which links python3